# Filter pivot table between two timestamps

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My pivot table is like: `2019/1/13 1:00`, `2019/1/13 4:00` … until `2019/3/12 23:00`.
I want to filter all the timestamps during `2019/2/13` to `2019/3/12`, including `2019/2/13 2:00`, `2019/2/13 6:00` …

Tried to use the following code

```
datecom = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 3, Day(Date))

dDate = Format(datecom + TimeValue("00:00:00"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
dDateto = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")

Set PvtTbl = sh.PivotTables("ROS-PVT5").PivotFields("IN Raised")

PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters
PvtTbl.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:=dDate, Value2:=dDateto
```

However, it will display as label filter and nothing returned.
How to use VBA for filter all time between two dates?

Comment: If your dates in the PivotTable are actually real dates and not strings you must remove `Format` from `dDate = Format(datecom + TimeValue("00:00:00"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")` and just use a real date `dDate = datecom + TimeValue("00:00:00")` same for `dDateto` which should be `dDateto = Now()`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Do I still need to use the xlCaptionIsBetween? I tried your suggestion but no luck..

Comment: Did you try doing it manually while recording it with the Macro Recorder. This could an easy way to find out how the code would look like.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Using manual macro it will just set the single item to visible..

Comment: First you need to get it working manually. Because if that doesn't even work then you have another problem and your issue is not in the code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Variable Names

First of all you should **not use a variable name "PvtTbl" for a PivotField** - that is misleading and easily results in misunderstandings or errors!

I suggest to use `Option Explicit` above each module and declare e. g. like this:

```
Dim PvtTbl as PivotTable
Dim PvtFld as PivotField
```

---

## xlCaptionIsBetween vs. xlDateBetween

Instead of `xlCaptionIsBetween` I recommend to use `xlDateBetween` to compare date values! The first one does a text comparison and works in your case only by pure chance as you have a date format with year/month/day notation.

---

## Example

A date filter only works on a `RowField` or a `ColumnField`, but neither on the pivottable itself nor on a `PageField` (which is a filter field. There you may use a time slicer).

If your Pivotfield is a row or column field and if you have datetime values in it, then its `PivotFilter` needs the values as `String` (as you already did).

I suggest to use `Add2`, use the type `xlDateBetween`, typecast each datetime with `CStr` and use `WholeDayFilter`:

```
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.RowFields("IN Raised")
PvtFld.ClearAllFilters
PvtFld.PivotFilters.Add2 _
    Type:=xlDateBetween, _
    Value1:=CStr(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, Day(Date))), _
    Value2:=CStr(Date), _
    WholeDayFilter:=True
```

Only if you can't work with full days and need to exclude some hours, then use formatted strings including hour information as you already did and `WholeDayFilter:=False`.

In any case it is not necessary to add a TimeValue("00:00:00"), as that is just equal to 0.

Comment: Hi Asger, I have an error "Application-defined or object-defined error"...

Comment: I was misled by your variable name, so I edited my answer to give some more explanations and recommendations.

Answer (score -1):

It works like the following. No idea it is because I re-open that worksheet..

```
dDate = Format(datecom, "yyyy/m/dd")
dDateto = Format(Now(), "yyyy/m/dd")


'''''''''''Pivot 5
Set PvtTbl = sh.PivotTables("ROS-PVT5").PivotFields("IN Raised")

PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters

PvtTbl.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:=dDate, Value2:=dDateto
```